# Writing an UPDATE query with LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables named `TableA` and `TableB`. Both `TableA` and `TableB` contain the following columns: `name`, `member_id`. `TableB` currently contains the "correct" values for `member_id`, whereas `TableA` does not.

What I'd like to do is migrate all of the values in column `member_id` of `TableB` to the respective column in `TableA` (matched by the values in column `name` column). However, sometimes the names are typed slightly differently between the two tables.

I wrote this following SQL query, though the subquery under `WHEN EXISTS` is not correct. Can someone assist me with this? Thanks.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET member_id = 
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT member_id
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.name ILIKE '%' || 'TableA.name' || '%'
    LIMIT 1)

    THEN member_id

    ELSE '1'
END
WHERE 
TableA.member_id = '0'
```

Also, I set it so that when the `member_id` is unknown, it is set to 0. The `ELSE '1'` cluase is to update the 0 to a 1 in the `member_id` column so that I know the query ran and modified that row already.

**Clarification: I wish to set** `TableA.member_id` = `TableB.member_id` **where** `TableA.name` **is similar to** `TableB.name`. **The 0 and 1 are for debugging, not the end goal.**

Comment: To begin with, `TableA.name` should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have `TABLEA.NAME` in quotes.  Remove them:

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET member_id = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT member_id
                                       FROM TableB
                                       WHERE TableB.name ILIKE '%' || TableA.name || '%'
                                      )

                          THEN member_id
                          ELSE '1'
                     END)
    WHERE TableA.member_id = '0'
```

Also, the `LIMIT 1` is not necessary, because you are checking for existence.

And, you could move the condition to the `where` clause, clarifying the logic (in my opinion):

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET member_id = '1'
    WHERE TableA.member_id = '0' and
          exists (SELECT member_id
                  FROM TableB
                  WHERE TableB.name ILIKE '%' || TableA.name || '%'
                 )
```

EDIT (in response to comment)

Here is one way to get the member id.  This approach is taking the maximum value.  By using an aggregation function, the query can use `coalesce()` in the aggregation to supply an unknown value:

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET member_id = (SELECT coalesce(max(member_id), 'Unknown')
                     FROM TableB
                     WHERE TableB.name ILIKE '%' || TableA.name || '%'
                    )
    WHERE TableA.member_id = '0';
```

And, finally, you can write this using `join` syntax:

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET TableA.member_id = TableB.member_id
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.name ILIKE '%' || TableA.name || '%' and
          TableA.member_id = '0'
```

If there are multiple matches, then the query will choose an arbitrary one.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, I wish to set TableA.member_id = TableB.member_id where TableA.name is similar to TableB.name. The 0 and 1 are to debug, not the end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative scenario without the need for `like`:

```
UPDATE TableA dst
SET member_id =  COALESCE ( src.member_id, -1 )
FROM (
        SELECT a.name , b.member_id
        FROM TableA a
        LEFT JOIN TableB b ON POSITION (b.name IN a.name) > 0
        ) src
WHERE  dst.name = src.name
AND dst.member_id < 10
        ;
```

NOTE: I changed member_id from character to numeric, which makes more sense to me.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( member_id INTEGER , name varchar);
CREATE TABLE TableB ( member_id INTEGER , name varchar);

INSERT INTO TableA(member_id,name) VALUES
(0, 'Jack' ), ( 1, 'Jill'), (2 , 'Bob'), ( 3, 'Alice' );
INSERT INTO TableB(member_id,name) VALUES
(11, 'ack' ), ( 12, 'ill'), (13 , 'Do'), ( 14, 'lic' );
```

RESULT:

```
 member_id | name  
-----------+-------
        11 | Jack
        12 | Jill
        -1 | Bob
        14 | Alice
```